# Categorical Cross Entropy Loss Derivation

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, cross-entropy, softmax

I understand the categorical cross entropy based loss function to be the following.

$$J(w) = \sum_{i=1}^ny_i\ln[P(y_i|x_i,w)]$$

where $$\ln\left[P(y_i|x_i,w)\right] = \sum_{i=k}^Kr_{ik}P(y_i=k|x_i,w)$$

$r_{ik} = 1$ if $y_i = k$ and $=0$ otherwise and

$$P(y_i = k|x_i,w) = \frac{e^{z_{ik}}}{\sum_{l=1}^K e^{z_{il}}}$$

The above makes perfect sense to me, but I was given the following equation and cannot see how I can get there from what I have so far....

$$J(w) = \sum_{i=1}^n\left[\ln\left[\sum_{k}e^{z_{ik}}\right]-\sum_kz_{ik}r_{ik}\right]$$

I can't tell if what was provided is incorrect/has poor notation, or if I am missing something...

Edit:

Should note that $$z_{ik} = (wx_i)_k + (w_0)_k$$

where $$w\in\mathbb{R}^{kxd}$$

Comment: What is $z_i$ and $z_{ik}$?

Comment: Is y different from r?

Comment: @mhdadk made the edit, should have been $z_{il}$ and $z_{ik}$ - defined above

Comment: @Sycorax good point, they are the same..